# Hibernate, Criteria, Projection, Transformer.aliasToBean and List<T> issue

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, criteria, projection

I want select an entity with some determined fields. Other fields let be NULL.
My issue...

EntA has refences to EntB and list of EntC.

---

```
class EntA {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "unique_id", strategy = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "unique_id")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 32, unique = true)
    private String id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entbs", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private EntB entB;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entcs", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<EntC> listEntC;
    ... other fields , getters & setters ...
}
```

---

A few days ago i had complemented bacis procedure of selection with folowing code. Code provides selection an object with some determined fields, other fields will be as null. Some like as SQL`s "select fieldA, fieldJ from table ..."

---

```
public List<EntA> select(..., List<String> fieldList, ...) {
    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EntA.class);

    ...

    ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
    for (String prop : fieldList) {
        pl.add(Projections.property(prop), prop);
    }
    crit.setProjection(pl);
    crit.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EntA.class));

    ...

    return crit.list();
}
```

---

All works good, for example: i select some fields (not all in entity) even repeat some field. Result = object of class EntA which has fields "id","EntB" and "other_field_name" with values, other fields are NULL.

---

```
List<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<String>();
fieldList.add("id");
fieldList.add("entB");
fieldList.add("entB");
fieldList.add("entB");
fieldList.add("other_field_name");
select(..., fieldList, ...);
```

```
Hibernate: 
    /* criteria query */ select
        this_.id as y0_,
        this_.entB as y1_,
        this_.entB as y2_,
        this_.entB as y3_,
        this_.other_field_name as y4_
    from
        EntA this_
Hibernate: 
    select
        entb0_.id as id1_12_0_,
        entb0_.idx as idx2_12_0_,
        entb0_.name as name3_12_0_ 
    from
        EntB entb0_ 
    where
        entb0_.id=?
```

---

But...

---

```
fieldList.add("id");
fieldList.add("listEntC");
select(..., fieldList, ...);
```

```
Hibernate: 
    /* criteria query */ select
        this_.id as y0_,
        this_.id as y1_ 
    from
        EntA this_
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultRow(CriteriaLoader.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    *************************************.select(BaseDao.java:141)
```

---

Several days i debug my code & hibernate-core sources and cant understand:
if i use simple selection without projections and transformers, i get normal object of EntA which List<EntC> lstEntC has values
if i use projection without transformers - i get not EntA
if i use projection with transformers, a can select only non-list fields

Have you any ideas about how to use Criteria`s selection with projection result into class?
thanks.